# Keyboard Shortcuts in Java Edition of Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, keyboard

Does anyone know any keyboard shortcuts that you can use in Minecraft Java Edition? (It can be in either Survival or Creative Mode)

e.g. `shift click` gets an entire stack or the greatest possible stack of an object (does not work when used when inventory open)

e.g. using hotbar keys to craft quickly

Comment: About your chess960 question, check out NM visualdennis' '[My Ultimate Guide to Chess960](https://lichess.org/@/visualdennis/blog/my-ultimate-guide-to-chess960/de25UOqM)', the [chess960jungle](http://chess960jungle.blogspot.com/) blog, etc. but in general the best way to get better at chess960 is to simply get better at chess middlegames and chess endgames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360059148111-Minecraft-Java-Edition-Hotkeys) is a list of all the shortcuts keys in Minecraft Java.

This is called Invariance and Covariance. If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.